# Khintchine's Recurrence Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, operator-theory, ergodic-theory

Yves Coudène. Ergodic Theory and Dynamical Systems. Page 14.

Roughly speaking he mentioned that the Khintchine's Recurrence Theorem is a generalisation of Poincaré's Recurrence Theorem.

How can Khintchine's Recurrence Theorem be considered to be a generalisation of Poincaré's Recurrence Theorem.

Comment: $\mu(A \cap T^{-n}A) \ge \mu(A)^2-\epsilon$ is stronger than $\mu(A \cap T^{-n} A) > 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Poincaré's recurrence theorem refers to single orbits, Khintchine
recurrence theorem refers to configurations and yields a quite optimistic conclusion
about the possibility to recover the initial state of a configuration from a sequence
of observations. In fact, it asserts the nonexistence of wandering configurations.

Comment: Thank you for your response.